# Is it better to use require_once('filename.php') or require_once 'filename.php';

Tags: php, require-once

Is this just a stylistic difference, or does using `require_once('filename.php')` vs `require_once 'filename.php'` have actual load/efficiency differences?

Comment: Just an extra character to type in the case of parentheses.

Comment: I'm getting different behaviour for the two. One path is written using dirname and another works relative to the site root. Very odd.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's exactly the same thing. It's a matter of style.

The parentheses may get in the way some times. For instance, this example from the manual doesn't do what you expect:

```
if (include('vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}
```

See [example #4](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Comment: But this is not caused by the parentheses.

Comment: I think you should include in the answer what it really does. `('vars.php') == 'OK'` is interpreted as the argument to `include` like in `if (include(('vars.php') == 'OK')) {`. That's why you should avoid using parentheses so it doesn't bring you to the wrong conclusion.

Answer (score 38):

Pear Coding Standards say :

> "include_once and require_once are statements, not functions.
>   Parentheses should not surround the subject filename."

Source : http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.including.php

Answer (score 12):

What does your heart tell you?

Performance difference, if any: negligible.

Comment: I just like that this can be a valid answer to a programming question!

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference. I don't use the brackets 'cause they are not necessary. require_once is no function.

Comment: "is no function" does not imply parentheses are not necessary (see `isset`, etc.).

Comment: That's not my implication - I only mention it ;)

Answer (score 1):

**`include`**, **`include_once`**, **`require`** and **`require_once`** are not functions, they are statements, that is why you should not use `()`.

**Also, consider this from php.net:**

```
<?php

// won't work
if (include('vars.php') == TRUE) {
    echo 'OK';
}

// works
if ((include 'vars.php') == TRUE) {
    echo 'OK';
}

?>
```